# Syntax and logic of subquery in SQL query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I was going through the SQL query given below.

```
 SELECT         
        a.`Cust_id`,    
        b.First_Name,
        b.Last_Name,
        b.Email
 FROM
        Customers AS a,
        (SELECT Cust_Fname,Cust_LName,Email
         FROM Cust_Info 
        )AS b
 WHERE
        a.`Product`='Pepsodent' #table b doesn't have Product column
 GROUP BY Cust_id     #Both tables 'a' and 'b' have Cust_id
 ;
```

I understand that I can use JOINS instead of subquery here but I am looking at this code from another point of view.

As far as my understanding goes, the code is retrieving information from two tables- *a and b* i.e it is getting *'Cust_id'* from table a and *First_Name,Last_Name,Email* from table b. It is also filtering the result set on the WHERE clause which is using just *Table a* in the condition. However, as the comment say both tables 'a' and 'b' have Cust_id.

So my question is- *how does table b know which cust_id to choose(since the condition is on table a only i.e. a.`Product`='Pepsodent')?* What is the logic involved here?

P.S. I am writing this query on SQLYog

Comment: This is a Cartesian product - a cross join, and only table a's cust_id is referenced in the SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that SQL joins the table for you, but since you didn't specify a condition what will happen is that you will get all combinations of those tables (cartesian product, in sql is called `CROSS JOIN`), for example if table `a` has 3 rows and `Cust_Info` has 2 rows, you will get 6 rows, then of course since the rows is partially data from `a` you can filter the product.

Also note that even if both tables have `Cust_id` your subquery is not selecting it, meaning that `b` doesn't have a column called like that, if this was not the case SQL couldn't know which column you where referring too and at that point you have to specify either `a.Cust_id` or `b.Cust_id`.